# Is there a way to mute music player when playing a Youtube video?

Tags: windows, audio, browser, youtube, foobar2000

Using Windows, [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) and a variety of browsers, is there a way to have foobar2000 muted/paused when currently active browser plays a youtube video ?
From what I understand, it is possible to force foobar2000 to have exclusive audio access using the [WASAPI plugin](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_out_wasapi), but that's clearly not what I want.

What I want is simple :

1. I have a playlist running on foobar2000
2. Meanwhile, I browse and find an interesting video to play
3. I usually pause my foobar2000 playlist and play the video instead.

Is it possible to automate step 3 ? (the best solution would be obviously to have any system sound auto-pausing and restarting foobar2000 (a kind of "sound card spy", I guess).

**EDIT** from other suggestions, this question has been forwarded to [hydrogenaudio forums](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=99466)

Comment: +1 interesting question. Currently I'm using a global hotkey CTRL+Space to [toggle pause/play](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hNGsA.png). But yours would be a far better solution.

Comment: @nixda I also have a hotkey ... a little bit more complex however (`Ctrl+Alt+Shit RightArrow`) but each time I have some sound output from my browser or any SSH session, or even a Windows sound, I find that intrusion in my music quite untasty. In fact I would easily go for a better Windows sound mixer allowing priorities between programs ... (an idea to explore).

Comment: I thought of the same. Have you asked over there on hydrogenaudio?

Comment: @nixda good idea, will do it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at mute.fm (http://www.mute.fm/).  I built this software to solve this problem generally and am looking for beta testers (anyone have other ideas of where to find them?).  Note that it is Windows 7 / Windows 8 Desktop only at this time.

Although the product does not have support for foobar2000, if there was a commandline that could be executed to do this, I could add such support fairly easily.  For now, it will just mute instead of pausing.

Comment: The reason why it needs .NET Framework 4 Full is due to dependencies (either the websocket library or the browser control.)  I'll spend time to identify the exact reason for that requirement and see if I can reduce it.


I don't blame your concern of installers.  Basically, it writes files within Program Files, modifies the registry to always run on startup (which you can turn off in settings), and installs another copy of Flash (required by the browser control that I use).  I'll look into posting a zip file later today so that the installation can be done manually.

Comment: FYI, the website links directly to the version of .NET needed (follow the hyperlink for .NET Framework 4 Full), although I should update the installer to tell the user that the link can be found on the download website (or ideally install .NET directly from the installer.)

Comment: I've updated the download page with instructions and files for manual installation; still need to look into what version of .NET is required.

Comment: You will get feedback tomorrow

Comment: Great, much appreciated.  Just verified that while the browser control works with .NET4 Client Profile, the websocket library that I am using (Superwebsocket) requires .NET4 Full.

Comment: Is there a technical problem with your mail server? Gmail couldn't send my mail to your support mail address "support@mute.fm".

Comment: Checking.  You can also send to mutefmapp at gmail.com.

Comment: @JaredSohn Do you mean you could pause foobar2000 as required provided the command-line was found in [wiki](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Commandline_Guide) ... Well, at first glance, i guess doing `foobar2000 /pause` and `foobar2000 /play` would do the job, no ?

Comment: Yeah, if those commands exist, then I should be able to get that working with a bit of effort.

Comment: A delayed update on this:  foobar2000 support has been added to the software.